# IF and ELSE IF executable same time Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, cordova

```js
    $scope.closeOk = function (e) {
            var xa = 0;
            if ($rootScope.viewImage==0&&$rootScope.openCaiDat==1&&$rootScope.openThread==1&&xa==0) {
                $('#caiDatKhiXem').modal('hide');
                xa=1;
                $rootScope.openCaiDat = 0;
                $scope.$digest();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                return true;
            } else if ($rootScope.viewImage==0&&$rootScope.openCaiDat==0&&$rootScope.openThread==1&&xa==0) {
                $rootScope.classHienThiBaiViet = "modal animated fadeOutRightBig";
                xa=1;
                $timeout(function () {
                    $('#hienBaiHome').modal('hide');
                }, 1000);
                $rootScope.tapToExit = 1;
                $rootScope.openThread = 0;
                $scope.$digest();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                return true;
            }
    };
```

Can anybody explain me why the two sections if and else if are executable same time. I just want one of them to be executed.

Please help me. Sorry for my english very bad

Comment: If you `return` in each branch then there is absolutely no way both branches run in the same function call. You are probably calling the function more than once.

Comment: share your code from where `closeOk` is calling ? definitely you are calling  this method multiple times, first time it comes inside `IF` and then always set true for `ELSE IF` by `$rootScope.openCaiDat = 0;`.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        $scope.closeOk();
    }, false);
}` <br>I just call it from other controllers. How to i break it when one of them executend.